# How can I undo my flags?

Tags: support, flagging

Salamu 'aleykum

I recently have been notified that 7 of my flags were declined. So now I'm retained for not flagging anymore. To undo this I thought maybe I can delete my old flags, but I don't see any button to perform this execution.

Please show me how to get rid of those 7 flags.

Wada'aan

Comment: I think flags can only be undone before passing the peer review.

Comment: Didn't they pass the peer review if my flags have been declined?

Comment: Actually the declination message is the result of the peer review. What I mean is if they have been reviewed by 5 users or and a mod.

Comment: Does that mean I can never flag on this site?

Comment: Hm.. Let me remember the old days... You might need to wait a couple of days I guess. You may try and see if you can. I experienced this a couple of times but honestly didn't care much I do flag when I think I should if it doesn't work I might retry it another day or leave it.

Comment: Oké, thanks for the answer. If you'd like you can put it below and I can accept it and upvote it.

Comment: It is better if somebody with more insight might answer I actually can hardly access the [help] to check the details. Beside I prefer to answer when I have certain basis of knowledge on the matter.

Comment: You can't you can only learn and avoid flagging one time to often in future.

Comment: Well I'm now able to flag. Maybe there is a certain time limit (I think exactly a week) if you too many flags were declined.